# Is there any quick or automated to way to check the version of PHP running on a remote server?

Tags: php

Currently running a vulnerability assessment. However, the IP I was provided is a load balancer and the client only wants to test one of the sites running on the load balancer. The vulnerabilities I have found are all PHP related. How can I confirm that their website is running that PHP version rather than another website on the load balancer? I already checked the headers and while it tells me the Apache version that it is running, nothing about PHP. Is there a tool or quick way to determine what the most likely version of PHP running it is?

Comment: you might be able to extract the PHP version either through an application running on the server, or indirectly. A certain version of the application may only run on PHP 5, or some application extension may leak the PHP version. Depends if your vulnerability assessment agreement allows for this or not.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the version information is presented to you, e.g. in headers, a call to `phpinfo()` in the code etc., there is likely no way to determine the version.

The only other way I can think of would be to try and exploit known vulnerabilities in PHP itself, and deduce the version based on success. However, this may or may not be appropriate for your assessment.

Comment: The second way you suggest is basically what I was thinking of. However I was thinking less exploits and more special "quirks" of certain PHP versions like formatting files in a certain way, or printing different banners. Is there no tool that consolidates all of those checks into one program or script?

Comment: @trallgorm it's possible that there are detectable quirks, not sure if a tool exists or how feasible it is. With banners, it's likely a matter of them being enabled or not.